# Binding Grid to a Linq Datasource from Winforms (.net)

Tags: .net, winforms, linq, linq-to-entities, grid

Back in the old days (i.e. last month) I'd bind my winforms grid to a dataset and be off and running.  By default the grid contents could be updated. (similar to an Excel spreadsheet)

But, if I bind a grid to a Linq datasource (either Linq to SQL or Linq to Entities) my winforms grid is locked into a read-only mode. How can I enable an update mode?

Comment: Deleted my answer.  Did some digging around in the DGV.  Seems like it handles ILists and IListSource implementations differently than others.  These go into CurrencyManagers that are updatable and others go into PropertyManagers that are not.  As to why ToList() fails I can't answer.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:  use lambda expressions to filter the entity and bind directly to the entity.

Answer (score 1):

Are you perhaps using an anonymous type in the projection? i.e.

```
select new {Foo = order.Foo, Bar = custmoer.Bar};
```

(or similar) - anonymous types in C# are immutable, so yes: it will seem read only. However, *regular* classes (either the LINQ-generated ones, or your own) should be editable. The only thing to remember is to call `.ToList()` on any query (rather than giving it the `IEnumerable<T>`/`IQueryable<T>` object).

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `GetNewBindingList` method on the various classes for 'better' binding.

And remember to call `SubmitChanges` when you are done.